# Create a Header in Sencha Touch application

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I think my question is very simple but since I just beginning to develop with Sencha Touch I have no idea how to do it.

Anyway, I want to create a UI with a Header, a List and a Navigation bar. I managed to create the list and the navigation bar already but I'm struggling to create the header. This is how my code currently looks like:

```
Ext.setup ({
icon: 'icon.png',
tabletStartupScreen: 'tablet_startup.png',
phoneStartupScreen: 'phone_startup.png',
glossOnIcon: false,

onReady: function()
{
    var tabpanel = new Ext.TabPanel
    ({
        tabBar: { dock: 'bottom', layout: { pack: 'center' } },
        fullscreen: true,
        ui: 'light',
        cardSwitchAnimation: { type: 'slide', cover: true },
        defaults: { scroll: 'vertical' },
        items: [tabAgora, tabCanais, tabProcurar, tabAlarme]
    });
} });
```

And this is my result so far: **http://i.imgur.com/zexsf.png**

But what I'm trying to achieve is something like this: **http://i.imgur.com/vmOoS.png** (header marked in red)

Can somebody show me the code to have the navigation bar at the bottom and the header at the top in the same window?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to tabs of a tabpanel, you can also add items, wich are docked via *docked* config option, like this:

```
    ...
    defaults: { scroll: 'vertical' },
    items: [tabAgora, tabCanais, tabProcurar, tabAlarme, {
        xtype: 'navigationbar'
        docked: 'top',
        title: 'icons',
        items: [{
            align: 'left',
            text: 'Navigation'
        }, {
            align: 'right',
            text: 'Source',
            ui: 'action'
        }]
    }]
```